Use Variables in filters of Entity GraphQL API
I am consuming an Entity GraphQL API uisng straberry shake graphQL client. The filtering of the graphql API works as mentioned in this Link
My schema is as below:
type Client {
  .....
  clientCode: String
  clientName: String
  .....
  .....
}

type ClientPage {
  items: [Client!]!
  hasPreviousPage: Boolean!
  hasNextPage: Boolean!
  totalItems: Int!
}

type Query {
  ....
  ....
  clients(filter: String sort: [QueryClientsSortInput] skip: Int take: Int = 10): ClientPage
  ....
  ....
}

It can be noted that the filter is of type string. The below query works and returns data as expected.
query GetClientsByName{
    clients(filter: "clientName == \"abcd\"")  
    {
        hasNextPage
        hasPreviousPage
        items {
            clientCode
            clientName
        }
        totalItems
    }
}

But since the filter just supports string type. I am unable to use a query variable here.
I am expecting something like this:
query GetClientsByName($clientName: string){
    clients(filter: "clientName == $clientName")  
    {
        hasNextPage
        hasPreviousPage
        items {
            clientCode
            clientName
        }
        totalItems
    }
}

or
query GetClientsByName($clientName: String){
    clients(filter: {clientName: {eq: $clientName}})  
    {
        hasNextPage
        hasPreviousPage
        items {
            clientCode
            clientName
        }
        totalItems
    }
}

I could not find any mention of such queries in the Entity GraphQL documentation.
Can Entity GraphQL support any one of the above mentioned two querying capabilities (query variable in sting filter or filter expressions)?
